# Is Earth gaining energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, temperature, thermal-radiation, geophysics

Since we can get energy from the Sun, either directly or indirectly through  fossil fuels, and we can use this energy to drive our motors which release energy in the form of heat (back into the atmosphere), kinetic, sound, or electricity.

But we are not really releasing the energy originally acquired from the sun back into the universe.

So is Earth, as a system, gaining energy as time passes?

Comment: If you want to go beyond the black-body planet calculations, you need start dealing with the details of how the balance of incoming & outgoing radiation work at the top of the atmosphere, which becomes a surprisingly complicated business and is one of the main things that climate scientists deal with.  Looking up the term 'solar forcing' is a good place to start.

Answer (score 2):

You said

> But we are not really releasing the energy originally acquired from the sun back into the universe.

Why not? Earth has a non-zero temperature and thus it is radiating like a black body releasing energy outside. We can even try to evaluate the Earth temperature by requiring such a balance between receieved and radiated energy. Every black body radiates a power per unit area given by **Stefan-Boltzmann law**

$$j=\sigma T^4$$

where $\sigma$ is the **Stefan-Boltzmann constant**. Lets denote by $R_{\rm sun}$ the sun's radius, by $R_{\rm Earth}$ the Earth radius and by $L_{\rm sun}$ the distance between Earth and sun. It is straight forward to see that the power that arrives the Earth surface is

$$P_{\rm in\:Earth}=\pi R_{\rm Earth}^{2}\frac{4\pi R_{\rm sun}^2}{4\pi L_{\rm sun}^2}\sigma T_{\rm sun}^4=\pi R_{\rm Earth}^{2}\frac{R_{\rm sun}^2}{L_{\rm sun}^2}\sigma T_{\rm sun}^4$$

This power should be balanced by the power emitted by Earth

$$P_{\rm out\:Earth}=4\pi R_{\rm Earth}^2\sigma T_{\rm Earth}^4$$

Comparing those expressions we obtain

$$T_{\rm Earth}=\sqrt{\frac{R_{\rm sun}}{2L_{\rm sun}}}T_{\rm sun}\approx 280^\circ{\rm K}\approx 7^\circ{\rm C}$$

which is not too far from the average temperature of Earth which from the internet is around $14^\circ{\rm C}$. This implies that we are not far from equilibrium with the Earth environment.

Comment: Don't forget Earth's primordial heat is still radiating along with radioactive decay on the inside.

Comment: @JEB Sure there are a lot additional effects to consider. Yet, a rough thermodynamic analysis of black body radiation yields very interesting results. Do you think you can estimate the effect you've mentioned and calculate corrections to the result I showed?

Comment: Each contributes to about 25 TW of energy, that the Earth is losing, per the OP's question. It's not significant for your equilibrium analysis.

Comment: Compounding factors: 1) The atmosphere, clouds, and reflective surface of the earth (i.e., albedo >0) reflect some of the incoming radiation back into space;  2) "Greenhouse" gases capture some of the outgoing IR radiation and re-emit back towards the earth.